# FDT Cannot compile for iOS "compile-abc: Permission denied"

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, adobe, fdt

I'm getting the following error when compiling for iOS in FDT (OSX):

```
Packaging failed!
Packaging error message: 
Compilation failed while executing : compile-abc
Packaging output: 
/var/folders/96/gkk__zq13zg7z70dlp_lnw580000gq/T/cmd973180567546602806.tmp: line 2: /Users/ben/Documents/work/resources/flash/flex_sdk_4.6.0/lib/aot/bin/compile-abc/compile-abc: Permission denied
/var/folders/96/gkk__zq13zg7z70dlp_lnw580000gq/T/cmd6338527548194546742.tmp: line 2: /Users/ben/Documents/work/resources/flash/flex_sdk_4.6.0/lib/aot/bin/compile-abc/compile-abc-64: Permission denied
```

I'm using the AIR 18 Beta, I've tried with 17 with the same issue.

I've had to use Java 1.7 rather than 1.6 as this is a requirement for the latest version of FDT.

I've created a clean project with no additional libraries but I'm still seeing the issue.

I can compile for desktop and Android without the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Ben

Answer (score 1):

check out these links:

http://www.flashdeveloper.co/post/111191611037/compilation-failed-while-executing-compile-abc

http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/cannot-build-with-air-16

Also please keep in mind, that you use an AIR BETA version.

Maybe you could also check, if your SDK user access rights are set.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried with air 17 so its not a beta issue.

Comment: I've tried with AIR 15 and getting the same issue. If I compile with 15 and use the standard not the improved engine I get a slightly different error: "Compilation failed while executing : as"

Comment: Did you used AIR 15 and legacy AOT?

Comment: everyone has Read&Write, is this what you mean?

Comment: I've managed to get it to compile with FDT 5.6 and Air 3.3 but this obviously isn't ideal.

Comment: This issue sits in the compiler as you see from the above articles. Should actually land as a bug for Adobe AIR :/